# MongoDB collection query/aggregate logical problem while elements duplicated

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection which looks like this:

```
data = [
{number: 1,
status: "ERROR",
date: "2020-02-02"},
{number: 1,
status: "OK",
date: "2020-02-03"},
{number: 2,
status: "ERROR",
date: "2020-03-02"},
{number: 2,
status: "OK",
date: "2020-03-03"},
{number: 3,
status: "OK",
date: "2020-04-02"},
{number: 4,
status: "ERROR",
date: "2020-04-03"}
]
```

I have some object. Some of them contain the same number, but the status is different.
I would like to find all the elements, but if the number is shown twice or more i would like to find just that one which status is "OK"

I tried to aggregate the collection, and group the object via number, than match those which status is "OK", but then i have no got those object which show just once in the array.

I tried to filter the array:

```
const b = data.filter((v,i,a)=>a.findIndex(t=>(t.number === v.number))===i)
```

but it give the first value if number equals, no matter of which is the status

if i try to implement the status query than every value get back:

```
const b = data.filter((v,i,a)=>a.findIndex(t=>(t.number === v.number) && t.status === "OK")===i)
```

I'm stuck, can anybody help me ?

The expected value is:

```
data = [
{number: 1,
status: "OK",
date: "2020-02-03"},
{number: 2,
status: "OK",
date: "2020-03-03"},
{number: 3,
status: "OK",
date: "2020-04-02"},
{number: 4,
status: "ERROR",
date: "2020-04-03"}
]
```

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

- `$sort` by status in descending order (this will bring OK status's objects in top)
- `$group` by number and get first document from group objects (this will pick first sorted object)
- `$replaceWith` to replace root object in root
- `$sort` if you want to sort by number then the will order in ascending order by number (just commented)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $sort: { status: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$number",
      root: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  { $replaceWith: "$root" },
  // { $sort: { number 1 } } // (optional)
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yDz_KaVMJj_)